# Remove entire column from the table programmatically in twig file

Tags: views, theming, 8

In my twig file `views-view-table--myview.html` by default a table is coming with header and rows. And I want to remove entire column from the table programmatically in twig file.

How it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

User `hook_views_pre_view()`checkout this code snippet.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_view().
 */
function MY_MODULE_views_pre_view($view, $display_id, array &$args) {

  if ($view->id() == 'view_name' && $display_id == 'page_1') {
    $view->removeHandler($display_id, 'field', 'name_of_your_column');
  }
}
```

Bingo!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't think the twig file is the right place for that. 
It sounds more like a preprocess, or view alteration.